# i'm able to search google using cURL but ajax is returning null

Tags: php, ajax, curl

i'm unable to `return $data`  when i do `echo $data` the page will load(see arrow ---> **getPage.php**).

but i want return `$data` to **page1.php** i will get `{"html":null,"url":"floret media"}`  you can see here `"html":null` why it is happening? when i replace `return $data` to `echo $data` in `response tab` i see this(with WHOLE PAGE)

```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2016 09:24:01 GMT Expires: -1
> Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 Content-Type: text/html;
> charset=ISO-8859-1 P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See
> https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more
> info." Server: gws X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Frame-Options:
> SAMEORIGIN Set-Cookie:
> NID=93=XFlY_DE0XhLLdLDiTeHZi44J_z61nRxwTBInVkZlRVA3MsnuhB3iAqcR12lMs44dRI3dMWriif3USxysmiXDqm317uTYg08TzgYzFZa-VVgII_KE5fVsxueZcAmzlMCrOCw1LCSPCuIKfVI;
> expires=Wed, 28-Jun-2017 09:24:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com;
> HttpOnly Accept-Ranges: none Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding:
> chunked

<!doctype html><html itemscope="" ><!--WHOLE PAGE --></html>
```

> is browser is not allowing to return response to calling ajax?

**page1.php**

```
var url = 'floret media';
$.ajax({
         url:"getPage.php",
         type:"POST",
         dataType:"json",
         data:{url:url},
        success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);

                 }
    });
```

**getPage.php**

```
    function curl_google($keyword){ 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
    'http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q='.urlencode($keyword).'&btnG=Google+Search&meta='); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    //ob_flush();//Flush the data here
    if ($data === FALSE) {

        echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);

    }
    curl_close($ch); 

  ------>  return $data;  <---- // when i change it to echo $data it will work, but return $data; will not work i will get json response as {"html":null,"url":"floret media"}
    } 


$url = $_POST["url"];

$html = curl_google($url);


$response = json_encode(array("html"=>$html,"url"=>$url));

echo $response;
```

Comment: in your page1 data:{url:url)}, it should be data:{url:url}, rt? ')' you are placing extra

Comment: @Amruthls, that is typing mistake i will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the html response with utf8_encode. Replace the following statement

```
$response = json_encode(array("html"=>$html,"url"=>$url));
```

with

```
$response = json_encode(array("html" => utf8_encode($html), "url" => $url));
```

Since the response returned from Google is having some non-utf8 characters, which result to null while performing json_encode.